# Using dependency injection but need to convert json to poco

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I want to implement DI for a console app I am working on as I see the benefits of low coupling and as I want to write some tests, I am having issues writing proper mocks for some objects.

My app is as follows

It takes 2 args into main and one of the args is a filepath that contains a JSON file.

I take this json file and convert and validate it using Validation attributes and deserialize it into an object.

Once this poco is ready, I want to then add a service to my dependency injection that depends on the poco.

So it is something like this

dotnet run arg1 arg2

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   // arg1 = filepath, check if file exists

   // Load JSON, validate, convert to POCO
   IConfigurationRoot config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile(args[0]).Build();

   MyPOCO poco = new();

   // This will fill the poco and validate. Throws exception of list of errors, if any. Otherwise, continues
   config.BindValidate(poco);

   // Now I'm in a state where I can inject my object
   var someClass = new SomeService(poco);

   // Would this be consider the correct way? Could I do all this validation and then inject this someClass service into my DI? This is just a mockup but the idea would be the same using the DI libraries? I'm not sure which route to take for this.
}
```

This is just a mock up but is there an approach I could use for this?

I need the SomeService class to be decoupled as I want to mock this class in my tests. Currently, this class is being initialized within a method.

I see that SomeService does have a dependency on MyPOCO so I could in theory just inject the MyPOCO and SomeService into my DI container as well. However, it would have to be the same instance that was validated for MyPOCO (not sure if DI can take an initialized object? Not sure if AddSingleton can take the instance perhaps?)

Open to expanding and providing more context if needed.

EDIT

```
   public static class ConfigurationExtensions
   {
      public static void BindValidate(this IConfiguration root, object instance)
      {
         root.Bind(instance, co => co.BindNonPublicProperties = true);
         var validationContext = new ValidationContext(this, null, null);               
         var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();               
         var valid = Validator.TryValidateObject(instance, validationContext, validationResults, true);
         
         if(!valid)
         {
            // Print errors if any here and throw exception, if any
         }           
      }
   }
```

Comment: Does Poco come from your appsetting.json?

Comment: I don't call it appsettings.json but it is similar. Contains certain data required for initialization of the service.

Comment: It's a matter of knowing how you would evaluate the poco. if it's in the appsetting then you can bind it from IConfiguration.

Comment: I have an extension method called BindValidate that I calls `Validator.TryValidateValue`

Comment: I will edit my answer to include this method

Comment: Since you're using configuration anyway, then I'd suggest reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Comment: @sa-es-ir the problem is Bind is just one part but I want to also validate as well so I just combine the two into the extension method instead

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I see this section https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-8.0#options-validation that may be very helpful. Seems like I can do `builder.Services.AddOptions<MyConfigOptions>()
            .Bind(builder.Configuration.GetSection(MyConfigOptions.MyConfig))
            .ValidateDataAnnotations();`. Will this do the validation after I call my object or before it is added to the container? Thank you for this seems like a great resource EDIT: there is a `ValidateOnStart` method so I can add this!